# Can I hardcode an enode hex-section in a local network?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, enode

I have multiple devices with unique IP's. Is there a way to attribute the same enode hex to all of them (while still having unique IP's contained in the enode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: no.

The hex part of the enode address is the public key of the node. It's the one generated from the node's private key. Having the same public key would mean having the same private key on all your nodes which would not work as they would be considered as the same node and conflicts would happen. Your private keys have to be specific for each node.

Comment: According to your answer: If I want to connect two peers/nodes, the minimum amount of bytes for are required to exchange is the enode.

The enode can be up to 169B, which is more than the payload of my communication module. Is there a way to reduce public key length?

Comment: @AlexPacheco I'm not sure to understand what you want to do. What do you mean by restrictions of your communication module? Don't you use a regular computer?

Comment: And no I don't think you can reduce pub key length if you want to be compatible with existing network. However you can modify a client of you choice and create your own version of Ethereum with smaller keys but it won't be able to peer with regular nodes.

Comment: In the flair and in the tittle I mention private/local network. They are not supposed to peer with any node outside this local network. 

My nodes perform a greeting triggered by a certain event. When this occurs, they add each other as peers for a defined amount of time. However, before greeting, they have no memory/dont know each other. So they need to send the enode. Bandwith of this communication interface is just a few bytes via I2C, hence sending a full mainnet ethereum enode wont be possible.

Option 1) Reduce pub key size
Option 2) Store pub keys in each nodes memory

Comment: @AlexPacheco interesting, so yes I guess you could hack the P2P protocol to reduce key size but I'm not sure about how secure it's going to be. Just curious, what kind of device do you run and what client do you use?

Comment: I am using 20 Raspberry Pi zeros installed on mobile robots. I'm using geth to run PoA clique, but also going to experiment with PoW.

Comment: @AlexPacheco awesome. I hope you will succeed in hacking this.